# Import/Export DirectX Models 4.0+

Tags: export, add-on, import, file-format, directx

Is there any way to do it, I looked it up online a bit, but apparently a addon that existed for this (which I believe was export only) doesnt support newer blender versions.

Does anyone know of how to do this?
Maybe some way to make a script for Importing/Exporting .X files?